# C# Combobox user control does not funtion as it should

Tags: c#, combobox, user-controls

I am fixing a `c#` project that uses a user control named `CompleteComboBox`.

It functions partly.

1. The backspace does not work.
2. The first time the user enters a string into the `textbox` part, the list opens as it should, and stands on the right line. The second time - the list does not open but it does show the matched line in the `textbox` part. Then, if   i open the list  and start writing the beginning of one of the items but then click one of the items and press enter - this item is not selected rather the item that was selected while entering letters in the `text box` part.

Hope I am understood.

Here is the code:

```
 namespace BestInvest.UserControls
{
public partial class CompleteComboBox : System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
{
    public event System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler NotInList;

    private bool _limitToList = true;
    private bool _inEditMode = false;

    bool start;

    public CompleteComboBox()
        : base()
    {

        start = true;
        this.Text = ClsConsts.InitializeTextForCombo;

    }

    [Category("Behavior")]
    public bool LimitToList
    {
        get { return _limitToList; }
        set { _limitToList = value; }
    }

    protected virtual void OnNotInList(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (NotInList != null)
        {
            NotInList(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_inEditMode)
        {
            string input = Text;
            int index = FindString(input);

            if (index >= 0)
            {
                _inEditMode = false;
                SelectedIndex = index;
                _inEditMode = true;
                Select(input.Length, Text.Length);
                //base.DroppedDown = true;
            }
        }

        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnValidating(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.LimitToList)
        {
            int pos = this.FindStringExact(this.Text);

            if (pos == -1)
            {
                OnNotInList(e);
            }
            else
            {
                this.SelectedIndex = pos;
            }
        }

        base.OnValidating(e);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (start)
        {
            base.DroppedDown = true;
            //else
            start = false;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            base.DroppedDown = false;
            start = true;
        }

        _inEditMode = true;

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry, I do not really understand, what you mean by "does not function as it should"... What is the expected behaviour and what is the malfunction? Please clearify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is messy. Look at the `start` flag. It is not set to true in all cases you would expect. That's why first time behavior is different from second time.

Your `OnKeyDown` event will not trigger on all keys you would expect. That's why backspace doesn't work. There are several posts about detecting backspace out there: [See for example this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a08e187e-5683-4f10-b946-fef37a36b581/backspace-not-detected-as-keydown-event)

Comment: But, i need some more help. This is not my code so this is why fixxing it is a little bit harder. The backspace behavior does not really worry me. Where else should I set the start flag to true so the second time the combo box will indeed function as expected?

Comment: I am tying again, maybe my question was not clear anough. I really need some help. I put into fixing this problom quite a lot of time, but did not get to the right answer. My main question is: What should I change in the code so that when the user clicks a list item - the clicked list item will be selected and not the list item that is highlighted as result of the user's input in the textbox part of the combo?